# How to draw a Klein Bottle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

My attempt:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n1) at (0,0)  {};
  \node (n2) at (0,1)  {};
  \node (n3) at (1,0)  {};
  \node (n4) at (1,1)  {};
  \foreach \from/\to in {}
    \draw (\from) -- (\to);
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n3,n4/n2}
    \draw (\from) edge [->] (\to);
     \foreach \from/\to in {n2/n3,n4/n1}
    \draw (\from) edge [->>] (\to);
     \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n4}
    \draw (\from) edge [->>>] (\to);
  \foreach \from/\to in {}
    \draw (\from) edge [bend right] (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

doesn't work very well - this is what it outputs:

[image]

How can I get the arrow to not be at the tip, but rather in the middle of the edge?

Comment: The interwebz presents a much different view on what a [klein bottle](https://www.google.ca/search?q=klein+bottle&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CDAQsARqFQoTCPr6oJO4x8gCFQ8qiAodfSILng&biw=1366&bih=677) is...

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific: here, I'm looking at the delta-complex. If you're interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6r66kd9XVs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

1. With TikZ, using a style with a decoration:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

   \def\Singlearrow{{\arrow[scale=1.5,xshift={0.5pt+2.25\pgflinewidth}]{>}}}
   \def\Doublearrow{{\arrow[scale=1.5,xshift=1.35pt +2.47\pgflinewidth]{>>}}}
   \def\Triplearrow{{\arrow[scale=1.5,xshift=1.75pt +2.47\pgflinewidth]{>>>}}}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[
   line cap=round,
   marr/.style={
     decoration={
       markings,
       mark=at position 0.5 with {#1}
       },
     postaction={decorate}
   }
   ] 
   \path
     coordinate (n1) at (0,0)
     coordinate (n2) at (0,2)
     coordinate (n3) at (2,0)
     coordinate (n4) at (2,2);
   \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n3,n4/n2}
       \draw[marr=\Singlearrow] (\from) -- (\to);
   \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n3/n4}
       \draw[marr=\Doublearrow] (\from) -- (\to);
   \draw[marr=\Triplearrow] (n1) -- (n4);
   \draw[->]
     (0.35,1.3) arc (220:-40:8pt);
   \draw[->]
     (1.7,0.35) arc (-40:220:8pt);
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   ## Some remarks

   - I used `\coordinate`s instead of the original `\node`s, so the lines will  meet.
   - Changing the `line cap` to `round` gives better result at the verticae.
   - By default a decoration places the arrow tip, not its center, at the specified position. This produces ugly results (specially noticeable for composed arrows). Addressing this issue, there are some posts such as [Position arrow decoration by center, not by tip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222262/3954), but the automatic answers there are, unfortunately, outdated. I used instead a manual approach similar to the [`answer by Kpym`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222299/3954).
2. Using [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}
   \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
   \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \begin{tikzcd}[
   sep=2cm,
   cells={shape=coordinate},
   ]
     \ar[draw=none,r, "{\tikz\node[rotate=90,inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->](0,0) ;};  }" description]
     \ar[dash,r] 
   & 
   {} 
   \\
     \ar[draw=none,r, "{\tikz\node[rotate=270,inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->](0,0) ;};  }" description] 
     \ar[draw=none,u, "{\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->>](0,0) ;};  }" description] 
     \ar[draw=none,ur, "{\tikz\node[rotate=-45,inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->>>](0,0) ;};  }" description] 
     \ar[dash,r] 
     \ar[dash,u] 
     \ar[dash,ur] 
   & 
   {}
     \ar[draw=none,u, "{\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->>](0,0) ;};  }" description]
       \ar[dash,u]  
   \end{tikzcd}

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there a way to 'shrink' the nodes so that the edges meet at the common vertices?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Sure; see my updated answer.

Comment: Is there an easy way to center the arrow heads, so that the middle of the arrow heads are at the middle of the line and not the tip?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek This is possible, yes, but not as easy as I initially thought. I have a solution and will post it in some minutes.

Comment: Also, the arrows are a bit small like this. How can I make them bigger?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Please, make all requirements from the beginning. It's not nice to be editing answers every time you came up with a new request.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Please see my updated answer. Change the `scale` value according to your needs.

Comment: You're right, sorry - will do so in the future. Thank again!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I finally decided to use a "manual" solution that I think is enough for this case. Perhaps later I'll try to implement an automatic one, but I can't promise anything :)

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt You're welcome! I added now the missing arrow (I had only drawn initially the quotient space) and the arcs as in the linked video.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Answer updated again; this time I present an option using `tikz-cd`.