# Labeling of this diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

How can I add labels to the corners and arrows of the following diagram?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzcd}[
sep=2cm,
cells={shape=coordinate},
]
  \ar[draw=none,r, "{\tikz\node[rotate=90,inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->](0,0) ;};  }" description]
  \ar[dash,r] 
& 
{} 
\\
  \ar[draw=none,r, "{\tikz\node[rotate=270,inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->](0,0) ;};  }" description] 
  \ar[draw=none,u, "{\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->>](0,0) ;};  }" description] 
  \ar[draw=none,ur, "{\tikz\node[rotate=-45,inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->>>](0,0) ;};  }" description] 
  \ar[dash,r] 
  \ar[dash,u] 
  \ar[dash,ur] 
& 
{}
  \ar[draw=none,u, "{\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->>](0,0) ;};  }" description]
    \ar[dash,u]  
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting diagram]

The diagram stems from the question
[How to draw a Klein Bottle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273401/how-to-draw-a-klein-bottle)

Comment: This code nests tikzpictures. It is*not* safe to use.

Comment: What would be a safer method then?

Answer (score 2):

Your code unfortunately nests `tikzpicture`s, which can lead to uncontrollable results. However, you are already loading `decorations.markings`, and using it allows you to avoid the nesting. I add two ways to answer your question, one with `tikz-cd` and another one with plain Ti*k*Z. For your convenience, I define styles `->-`, `->>-` and `->>>-` for the single, double and triple arrows. (**EDIT**: For your convenience I added the reversed arrow styles.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{> at/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position
#1 with {\arrow{>};}}}},
->-/.style={> at=0.5},
->>-/.style={>
at/.list={0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength-1.5pt,0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength+1.5pt}},
->>>-/.style={>
at/.list={0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength-3pt,0.5,0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength+3pt}},
< at/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position
#1 with {\arrowreversed{>};}}}},
-<-/.style={< at=0.5},
-<<-/.style={<
at/.list={0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength-1.5pt,0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength+1.5pt}},
-<<<-/.style={<
at/.list={0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength-3pt,0.5,0.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength+3pt}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep=2cm,cells={nodes={text height=1em,minimum width=0.8em}}]
a
& 
b\ar[dash,l,-<-,start anchor=south west,end anchor=south east,"\ell_1"']
\\
c \ar[dash,u,->>-,start anchor=north east,end anchor=south east,"\ell_2"]
\ar[dash,r,->-,start anchor=north east,end anchor=north west,"\ell_3"']
\ar[dash,ur,->>>-,start anchor=north east,end anchor=south west,"\ell_4"]
& 
d \ar[dash,u,->>-,start anchor=north west,end anchor=south west,"\ell_5"]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (0,0) coordinate[label=above left:$a$] (a)
  (2,0) coordinate[label=above right:{$b$}](b) 
  (0,-2) coordinate[label=below left:$c$] (c)
  (2,-2) coordinate[label=below right:$d$] (d)
  (b) edge[->-,"$\ell_1$"'] (a)
  (c) edge[->>-,"$\ell_2$"] (a)
  (d) edge[->>-,"$\ell_5$"'] (b)
  (c) edge[->>-,"$\ell_3$"'] (d)
  (c) edge[->>>-,"$\ell_4$"] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How can I also label the arrows?

Comment: @PhilippWeder I added labels (didn't read carefully, sorry!).

Comment: thank you! If I want to change the direction of one arrow, why can't I just change start and end point?

Comment: @PhilippWeder You can. What do you mean? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried the following

`b \ar[dash,u,->>-,start anchor=south east,end anchor=north east,"\ell_2"]`

instead of


`b \ar[dash,u,->>-,start anchor=north east,end anchor=south east,"\ell_2"]`

Comment: @mathology In `tikz-cd`, an arrow always starts at the cell you are issuing the `\ar` command. So if you want to convert the arrow going from `b` to `a` into an arrow going from `a` to `b`, you need to replace `a
& 
b\ar[dash,l,->-,start anchor=south west,end anchor=south east,"\ell_1"']` by `a
 \ar[dash,r,->-,start anchor=south east,end anchor=south west,"\ell_1"] & b`. Alternatively, you could define decorations like `-<-` and so on in which you reverse the arrow in the decoration by replacing `\arrow{>};` with `\arrowreversed{>};`.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer