# Tikz: How to make the arrow bend along the curve in decoration?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-decorations

When I'm drawing a contour, I want to know how to make the arrow bend along the curve in `decoration`. Please see the example below.

**Here is my MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{bending} % Bend the arrow

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=0.3cm,bend]},
        decoration={markings,
        mark= at position .1 with {\arrow{>}},
        mark= at position .32 with {\arrow{>}},
        mark= at position .55 with {\arrow{>}},
        mark= at position 0.88 with {\arrow{>}}, % <----
        }
    ]
        \def\gap{0.3}
        \def\bigradius{3.4}
        \def\littleradius{0.5}
    \filldraw[postaction = {decorate}, thick ,fill=gray!40] 
    let 
        \n1 = {asin(\gap/2/\bigradius)},
        \n2 = {asin(\gap/2/\littleradius)}
    in
        (0+\n1:\bigradius) node[above right]{$R$}  arc (0+\n1:360-\n1:\bigradius) node[below left]{$C_{R}$} -- (0-\n2:\littleradius) arc (360-\n2:0+\n2:\littleradius) node[above right]{$\delta$} -- cycle;

        \fill (-1.2,0)  circle (3pt) ;
        \draw[->] (-1.2,-1) node[right]{pole} --(-1.2,-0.15);

        % axis
        \draw[-Latex] (-1.5*\bigradius,0) -- (1.5*\bigradius,0) node[below]{$\Re$} ;
        \draw[-Latex] (0,-1.2*\bigradius) -- (0,1.2*\bigradius) node[right]{$\Im$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
As you can see, the fourth arrow on the contour looks strange. I want it to bend along the curve, that's why I want to use `\usetikzlibrary{bending}`.
**But in the `decoration`, it seems that the arrow cannot be bent, and the `bend` command cannot take effect.**

I would like to ask is there any solution?

**One of my solutions:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{physics}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}% Bend the arrow

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=0.3cm,bend]},
        decoration={markings,
        mark= at position .1 with {\arrow{>}},
        mark= at position .32 with {\arrow{>}},
        mark= at position .55 with {\arrow{>}},
        % mark= at position 0.88 with {\arrow{>}},
        }
    ]
        \def\gap{0.3}
        \def\bigradius{3.4}
        \def\littleradius{0.5}
    \filldraw[postaction = {decorate}, thick ,fill=gray!40] 
    let 
        \n1 = {asin(\gap/2/\bigradius)},
        \n2 = {asin(\gap/2/\littleradius)}
    in
        (0+\n1:\bigradius) node[above right]{$R$}  arc (0+\n1:360-\n1:\bigradius) node[below left]{$C_{R}$} -- (0-\n2:\littleradius) arc (360-\n2:0+\n2:\littleradius) node[above right]{$\delta$} -- cycle;

        % draw an arrow alone
        \draw[thick,->] (300:\littleradius) arc (300:130:\littleradius) node[above]{$C_{\delta}$};
        
        \fill (-1.2,0)  circle (3pt) ;
        \draw[->] (-1.2,-1) node[right]{pole} --(-1.2,-0.15);

        % axis
        \draw[-Latex] (-1.5*\bigradius,0) -- (1.5*\bigradius,0) node[below]{$\Re$} ;
        \draw[-Latex] (0,-1.2*\bigradius) -- (0,1.2*\bigradius) node[right]{$\Im$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just an observation: The arrow is placed anchored by its tip and slope of the arrow is also determined slope of the curve at the tips position. A work-around could be to place the arrow centered with `mark= at position 0.875 with {\arrow[xshift=2pt]{>}}` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365490/123129) to [Position arrow decoration by center, not by tip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222262/123129)).

Comment: @dexteritas Thanks for your comment. This is indeed a solution, although it does not look elegant.

Comment: You can use the options `flex=1.1` or `flex'` like `\draw[thick,-{>[flex=1.1]}] (300:\littleradius) arc (300:130:\littleradius) node[above]{$C_{\delta}$}`

Comment: @AndréC But the `bend` option can automatically fit the curve without requiring me to manually adjust.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `hobby` library allows one to draw a smooth curve through a given set of points. With the `markings` library one can record a number of points along the path that one decorate, and then draw a bent arrow through those points. This is what the `bent arrow at` style below does. In its current form it hard codes the distance of the points that the length of the curve matches the length of the arrow in your example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{bending} % Bend the arrow
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}% smooth curve through a set of given points
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=0.3cm,bend]},
        bent arrow at/.style={decoration={markings,
            mark=at position {#1*\pgfdecoratedpathlength-0.15cm} with {\coordinate (bent arrow 1);},
            mark=at position {#1*\pgfdecoratedpathlength-0.05cm} with {\coordinate (bent arrow 2);},
            mark=at position {#1*\pgfdecoratedpathlength+0.05cm} with {\coordinate (bent arrow 3);},
            mark=at position {#1*\pgfdecoratedpathlength+0.15cm} with {\coordinate (bent arrow 4);
            \draw[-{Stealth[length=0.3cm,bend]}] (bent arrow 1) to[curve through={(bent arrow 2) .. (bent arrow 3)}]  (bent arrow 4) ;}
        }}
    ]
        \def\gap{0.3}
        \def\bigradius{3.4}
        \def\littleradius{0.5}
    \filldraw[postaction = {bent arrow at/.list={.1,.32,.55,.88},decorate}, thick ,fill=gray!40] 
    let 
        \n1 = {asin(\gap/2/\bigradius)},
        \n2 = {asin(\gap/2/\littleradius)}
    in
        (0+\n1:\bigradius) node[above right]{$R$}  arc (0+\n1:360-\n1:\bigradius) node[below left]{$C_{R}$} -- (0-\n2:\littleradius) arc (360-\n2:0+\n2:\littleradius) node[above right]{$\delta$} -- cycle;

        \fill (-1.2,0)  circle (3pt) ;
        \draw[->] (-1.2,-1) node[right]{pole} --(-1.2,-0.15);

        % axis
        \draw[-Latex] (-1.5*\bigradius,0) -- (1.5*\bigradius,0) node[below]{$\Re$} ;
        \draw[-Latex] (0,-1.2*\bigradius) -- (0,1.2*\bigradius) node[right]{$\Im$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Following your example, I don't need to change much in my code base.

Answer (score 7):

Purely for comparison, here is a version in [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html).  The default arrowheads in MP always follow the curve of the path.  This is more noticeable on the inner ring.

[image]

This is wrapped up in [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en) so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
% some control values
numeric delta, R, gap;
delta = 13; R = 89; gap = 3;

% axes and the region to fill
path re, im, region, little_ring, big_ring;
re = (left -- right) scaled 5/4 R;
im = re rotated 90;

little_ring = reverse fullcircle scaled 2 delta
         cutbefore subpath (1/2, 1) of re shifted (0, -gap)
         cutafter  subpath (1/2, 1) of re shifted (0, +gap);

big_ring = fullcircle scaled 2 R
         cutbefore subpath (1/2, 1) of re shifted (0, +gap)
         cutafter  subpath (1/2, 1) of re shifted (0, -gap);

region = little_ring -- big_ring -- cycle;

% do the filling first so it is on the bottom
% grey scale is just a single number between 0 and 1

fill region withcolor 7/8;

% use narrower arrowheads
ahangle := 36;

% draw the axes and the pole marker, with fine pen
drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1/4);
drawarrow re;
drawarrow im;
z1 = (-3 delta, 0); z2 = z1 shifted 16 down;
draw z1 withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam;
drawarrow z2 -- z1 cutafter fullcircle scaled 6 shifted z1;
drawoptions();
          

% bigger arrowheads for the integral path
ahlength := 6;
drawarrow subpath (0, 5) of region;
drawarrow subpath (5, 10) of region;
drawarrow subpath (10, 12.5) of region;
drawarrow subpath (12.5, 15.5) of region;
draw      subpath (15.5, 18) of region;

% add the labels
label.bot("Pole", z2);
label.rt("$\Re$", point 1 of re);
label.top("$\Im$", point 1 of im);
label.urt("$\delta$", point 8 of little_ring);
label.urt("$R$", point 0 of big_ring);
label.ulft("$C_\delta$", point 5.3 of little_ring);
label.ulft("$C_R$", point 7.6 of big_ring);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is indeed a very beautiful method. It seems very easy to use `Metapost` to draw a picture of math and physics. I'll try to learn its manual.